# Archer C60 TP Link refuses connectio

Tags: router, wireless-router

I got a brand new Archer C60 from TP-Link and it refuses a connection to `192.168.0.1` after I reset it. It always redirects to `192.168.0.1:8080` and then refuses any connection. The firmware version seems to be `2.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that if you simply do `192.168.0.1/index.html` it works. I think it is a bug